# Solaris: remap devices

Tags: solaris

I have iSCSI lun connected as /dev/rdsk/c2xxxxxxxx

need to rename it to /dev/rdsk/c1xxxxxxxx

how can I do this? Modifying /etc/path_to_inst doesn't help.

Comment: already did it but many thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run a reconfiguration boot after modifying path_to_inst.

Answer (score 2):

jlliagre> You need to run a reconfiguration boot after modifying path_to_inst.

… and that is done by issuing `reboot -- -r` from a running Solaris - just for reference.